# Cantor set as a set of continued fractions?

Tags: general-topology, continued-fractions

Does the classical cantor set have a nice description as a set of continued fractions?

I made a (superficial) search and didn’t find anything, but I’m very tired right now, so please forgive me that I don’t put more effort in asking this.

Comment: Would this help? http://books.google.com/books?id=9FAR-0A5tJgC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72

Comment: @FrankMcGovern I wouldn’t know, I can’t view it. But since you posted it, I’m positive it *would* help. : — D (It says I’ve reached the viewing limit, loosely translated.)

Comment: Oh dear. Maybe use a tunnelling site?

Comment: I don’t think that it actually helps: it just uses the result that $C+C=[0,2]$, where $C$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set, as motivation for a similar result about continued fractions with bounded denominators.