# Structure of the set of numbers with special continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

> Which structure does the set of numbers (possibly rational) with the property, that its continued fraction only contains the numbers $1$ and $2$, have ?

Let us denote the set of such real numbers with $S$.

$S$ contains numbers as $1$ , $2$ , $\ \sqrt{2}+1\ $ and $\ \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\ $. Since the set of infinite sequences with entries $1$ or $2$ is uncountable, there are uncountable many irrational numbers in $S$. Which elements of $S$ are limit points ? Is $S$ dense in a real interval ?

To avoid ambiguity, a number like $[1,2,1,1,2,2,1]$ is NOT in $S$ since it can be written as $[1,2,1,1,2,3]$, which has a "$3$".

Comment: S is certainly not everywhere dense; probably it is dense _nowhere_, much like the Cantor set.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That is my guess as well.

Comment: see http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-30

Comment: These are a special case of [restricted continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_partial_quotients). A very cursory glance at the link in the first comment under [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391806/cantor-set-as-a-set-of-continued-fractions) suggests that you probably do get a Cantor set, and you definitely get a set of measure $0$.